# Ubuntu 17.10 can't make wired connection work

Tags: connection, 17.10, wired, dsl

In ubuntu 17.10 **my wired connection isn't working** but **wifi** is working fine. I'm using a *Lenovo ideapad 320*. Ethernet cable is ok. I  also tried 16.04.3 LTS and 16.10 but I had the same problem when I tried to create a dsl connection.

Comment: Please specify your connection type. If you talk about cable, it seems you talk about Ethernet, not DSL. Do you have login credentials for PPPoE? Are these credentials entered in your DSL to Ethernet router? Do you have one?

Comment: Isp give me just like username c15@rakib & password "****".when i am create new profile on wired  then i was put credentials on 802.1xSecuirty . select Authentication:MD5 then put username and password and Select Ipv4 Mehtod Automatic(DHCP),Ipv6 Method Automatic.